# Codeigniter run jquery function again after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

How to apply jquery after Ajax Calling in codeigniter

my code of ajax calling

```
    function load_data_ajax(type){
    $.ajax({
        'url' : '/index.php?compose/get_list',
        'type' : 'POST', //the way you want to send data to your URL
        'data' : {'type' : type.value},
        'success' : function(data){ //probably this request will return anything, it'll be put in var "data"
            var container = $('#container'); //jquery selector (get element by id)
            if(data){
                $('#container').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My Html

```
        <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <font class="formpromp">Select Category: </font>
            <SELECT name="crs" onchange='load_data_ajax(this)'>
            <?php
                foreach($query as $rowcrs):
                    echo "<OPTION value='".$rowcrs['CD']."'>".$rowcrs['TITLE1']."</OPTION>\n";
                endforeach;
            ?>
            </SELECT>
    </td>   
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="container">
        <table id='table1' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><thead><tr>
        <th align='left'><input type='checkbox' value='' />Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>huzefa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>husain</td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

I am using Table filtergrid for table

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" id="t3">
        var tf = setFilterGrid('table1', props);
    </script>
```

ITS properly load First time, but i cant understand how to load java script after Ajax Data load.

Please any one help me.

Thanks

Comment: Just add  var tf = setFilterGrid('table1', props); to the success method of ajax

Comment: no its not working `code:  function load_data_ajax(type){
  $.ajax({
   'url' : '/index.php?compose/get_list',
   'type' : 'POST', //the way you want to send data to your URL
   'data' : {'type' : type.value},
   'success' : function(data){ //probably this request will return anything, it'll be put in var "data"
    var container = $('#container'); //jquery selector (get element by id)
    if(data){
     $('#container').html(data);
    }
    var tf = setFilterGrid('table1', props);
   }
  });
    }`